# Correspondence between Weil divisor and Cartier divisor on normal varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be normal singular projective variety over complex number, and $D$ be a Weil divisor on $X$. Is there an integer $n>0$ such that $nD$ is actually a Cariter divisor? If not, under  what condition on singularities  that is true, except the smoothness? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE! Please share your thoughts and tries on this question. This will also enhance your chances of a getting a good answer.

Comment: Ok. Here is what I know. A Cartier divisor always defines a Weil divisor. However the a Weil divisor is not necessary a Cartier one. See the follow example: X={xy=z^2} and D={y=0,z=0} is a Weil divisor, but not a Cartier one. Note that div(y)=2D, i.e. 2D is Cartier. So the question comes. I have no ideal how to prove it in general. Any reference is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: An normal variety with $Div_{\mathbb Q}(X)=WDiv_{\mathbb Q}(X)$ is called $\mathbb Q$-factorial. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73478/when-is-an-algebraic-variety-mathbbq-factorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the answer is "no." The simplest counterexample is the projective cone $V$ over a smooth cubic curve $C$ in $\mathbb P^2$. By some exercise or another in Hartshorne, Cl $V \cong$ Pic $C$, where the isomorphism comes from taking rulings over points in $C$. On the other hand, Pic $V$ is just $\mathbb Z\cdot \mathscr O(1)$. Anyway, the point being that if you take the ruling over a point of infinite order in the group law, no multiple of it is ever get a Cartier divisor.

Comment: Thanks. Q-factorial works. And I think  the ordinary double points of dim 3 is also a counterexample.